# Access XMLHttpRequest data in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

Most of the questions I find on classic ASP and XHRs are about how to create and send an XMLHttpRequest with classic ASP. In my case I want to read the data sent in the XHR with classic ASP.

I'm not at all familiar with classic ASP; I'm writing (as little code as possible) in VBScript. I've sent an XHR to the server, using POST as method, with request.send(data) in javascript.

How do I now access that data on the server. I'm guessing it's stored somewhere in the Request -object, but I can't find it or make it work. Is the data stored in Request.ServerVariables? Or do I need to use the BinaryRead method?

**EDIT**: per AnthonyWJones's comment, I didn't specify a data format. But I guess I'd like to be able to send plain text, JSON or x-www-form-urlencoded data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have helped if you had indicated what kind of data you were actually sending.  I'll assume you are posting up some XML.  In which case you can use the MSXML DOMDocument Load method.

```
  Dim xml: Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
  xml.async = False
  xml.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  xml.Load Request
```

Note the passing of the ASP Request object directly to the `Load` method.  Its not well documented by the ASP Request object implements the standard COM `IStream` interface, hence any that can read its data from an `IStream` (like DOMDocument`) can be passed the ASP Request object.

Comment: Wow. 12 years of ASP and I never knew Request implements IStream :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I suppose I create a different object if I send different types of data? like CreateObject(some_JSON_specification)? Where could I find the different parameters to the CreateObject() function?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer, which is totally correct, you can also set:

```
xml.validateOnParse = true
```

Or false, depending on your preference.

As to:

> "Where could I find the different parameters to the CreateObject() function?"

There are so many different objects you can create.  It depends on what's installed on your server.  Like you may not have the .3.0 dom document.  Devguru has a list of some of the built in objects, like filesystem, dictionary, etc: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/13990.asp.

Other common ones are CDONTS.Mail for mail, strCat.Catter, ADODB.Recordset/Command, MSxml2.ServerXMLHttp, WScript.Shell, various encryption objects, various 3rd party utilities like from SoftArtisans or IPWorks, etc.